# Unable to construct the link tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript. I am not able to construct a href tag with a variable appended. Below is the code and I want to append the tag_id to the href attribute.

Desired href format: /dashboard/#/summary/1008
  Current href format: /dashboard/#/summary/

```
function(data, type, full) {
                 return ( data == null ) ? "--" :"<span class='label label-success'><a href='/dashboard/#/summary/'+ tag_id>"+ data.tag_name+"</a></span>" ;
              }
```

Could you please let me know where I am going wrong. Please help me in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Will work. I think it will be data.tag_id. But considering tag_id will be available to you.

```
function(data, type, full) {
                 return ( data == null ) ? "--" :"<span class='label label-success'><a href='/dashboard/#/summary/'"+tag_id+">"+ data.tag_name+"</a></span>" ;
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change following:

```
"<span class='label label-success'><a href='/dashboard/#/summary/'+ tag_id>"+ data.tag_name+"</a></span>"
```

To this:

```
"<span class='label label-success'><a href='/dashboard/#/summary/" + tag_id + "'>" + data.tag_name + "</a></span>"
```

Also, make sure `tag_id` is available within the scope of your function. I think `tag_id` should be `data.tag_id` because you have `data.tag_name` unless you have another `tag_id` in the global scope. So, according o that, it should be:

```
"<span class='label label-success'><a href='/dashboard/#/summary/" + data.tag_id + "'>" + data.tag_name + "</a></span>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting data.tag_name. Same as you have to get tag_id as well. This is basic idea

Example: `<a href="http://www.example.com/summarry/**value_id**">**Value_name**</a>`

Same idea we have to use here

```
 function(data, type, full) {
                     return ( data == null ) ? "--" :"<span class='label label-success'><a href='/dashboard/#/summary/'+ data.tag_id>"+ data.tag_name+"</a></span>" ;
                  }
```